# How to remove socket.io default parameters

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I want to connect the web socket API of an external server using Vue2.
So, I installed the socket.io library.
However, when I run it, parameter values ​​that I do not want are entered.

Request URL: wss://loki.test.shop/loki/api/v1/tail?query={app=%22test-api%22}/?EIO=4&transport=websocket
parameter values ​​that I do not want are entered : /?EIO=4&transport=websocket

After checking the official documentation, it appears to be the default parameter value.
So I searched and found that I need to change the source code on the server and client sides.
But the websocket API is an external API that I cannot touch.
What action should the front office take to remove the default parameter values?

help me please.

Below is the code I wrote.

```
ioclientConnect(){
      const wssUrl = 'wss://loki.test.shop'
      const socket = io(wssUrl, {
        path: '/loki/api/v1/tail?query={app=%22test-api%22}',
        transports: ["websocket"],
        extraHeaders: {
          'X-Scope-OrgID': 'test'
        },
        cors: {
          origin: "*",
        },
        timestampRequests: false
      })

      socket.on('message', (message)=>{
        console.log('receive', message)
      })
    }
```

Comment: if the API you're connecting to is a websocket api, why are you using socket.io? You do know browsers can make websocket connections natively? (even internet explorer!!!) - in fact, socket.io is just a library that uses websockets in the browser ... in fact, socket.io uses websockets, so what you're doing makes no sense if the API is a websocket API

Comment: Yes, I know WebSocket is provided by default. However, this one does not allow me to add header values, so I am looking for another method.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to control or remove these parameters directly on the server side.

However, on the client side, you can modify the configuration to prevent these parameters from being added to the URL. Your current configuration is:

```
const socket = io(wssUrl, {
  path: '/loki/api/v1/tail?query={app=%22test-api%22}',
  transports: ["websocket"],
  extraHeaders: {
    'X-Scope-OrgID': 'test'
  },
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
  timestampRequests: false
})
```

Try removing the transports and timestampRequests options:

```
const socket = io(wssUrl, {
  path: '/loki/api/v1/tail?query={app=%22test-api%22}',
  extraHeaders: {
    'X-Scope-OrgID': 'test'
  },
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
})
```

Comment: When I do this, a CORS error occurs and /?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OmFmjC5 is added as a parameter.
The problem has not been resolved ㅜㅜ